# SpringBoot problem - @RestControllerAdvice executes before AuthenticationEntryPoint

Tags: java, spring

I have a problem with my SpringBoot App.
Namely I use jwt token auth in my springboot app.

```
@Component
public class AuthEntryPointJwt implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthEntryPointJwt.class);

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {
        int httpStatus = HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED;

        logger.error("Unauthorized error: {}", authException.getMessage());

        response.setStatus(httpStatus);
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String jsonResponse = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(authException.getMessage());
        response.getWriter().write(jsonResponse);
    }
}
```

```
public class AuthTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Autowired
    private JwtUtils jwtUtils;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthTokenFilter.class);

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String jwt = parseJwt(request);
            if (jwt != null && jwtUtils.validateJwtToken(jwt)) {
                String username = jwtUtils.getUsernameFromJwtToken(jwt);

                UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication =
                        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails,
                                null,
                                userDetails.getAuthorities());

                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Cannot set user authentication: {}", e);
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private String parseJwt(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String jwt = jwtUtils.getJwtFromCookies(request);
        return jwt;
    }
}
```

And I have some methods in a service that might throw: **EntityNotFoundException** or **AccessDeniedException**.

And my controller has @PreAuthorize.

So I added:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(EntityNotFoundException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public ErrorMessage handleEntityNotFoundException(EntityNotFoundException ex, WebRequest request) {
        return new ErrorMessage(
                HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value(),
                new Date(),
                ex.getMessage(),
                request.getDescription(false));
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(AccessDeniedException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
    public ErrorMessage handleAccessDeniedException(AccessDeniedException ex, WebRequest request) {
        return new ErrorMessage(
                HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value(),
                new Date(),
                ex.getMessage(),
                request.getDescription(false));
    }
}
```

but I noticed when a method throws **AccessDeniedException** class **GlobalExceptionHandler** executes before **AuthEntryPointJwt**.

When my jwt token is valid it works, but when is invalid then

```
    @ExceptionHandler(AccessDeniedException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
    public ErrorMessage handleAccessDeniedException(AccessDeniedException ex, WebRequest request) {
        return new ErrorMessage(
                HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value(),
                new Date(),
                ex.getMessage(),
                request.getDescription(false));
    }
```

executes before

```
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {
        int httpStatus = HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED;

        logger.error("Unauthorized error: {}", authException.getMessage());

        response.setStatus(httpStatus);
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String jsonResponse = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(authException.getMessage());
        response.getWriter().write(jsonResponse);
    }
```

so when a jwt token is invalid my spring boot returns **403 Forbidden** instead of **401 Unauthorized**.

WebSecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    private final UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
    private final AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;

    @Autowired
    public WebSecurityConfig(UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService, AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.unauthorizedHandler = unauthorizedHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();

        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception {
        return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .exceptionHandling(exception -> exception.authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler))
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->
                        auth.requestMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/api/test/**").permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                );

        http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());

        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Why?
Thank you in advance.